# Counter not displaying each number, just shows final total

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, event-loop

Why is it that the counter only shows final number vs seeing each number 1 by 1.
What needs to be done to accomplish this?

```
var counter = 100;
function countdown() {

 while(counter < 1000) {
    
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
    document.getElementById('cc').innerHTML = counter;

  }
}
    
countdown();
setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

Comment: That is because the browser updates the DOM in batches: you're basically letting the while loop run as fast as possible to increment the `counter`. The setInterval doesn't do what you expected (which I guess is to increment by 1 per millisecond). Can you tell us what you want to achieve: tween the value over the time of 1000ms, or increment every 1000ms?

Comment: Please explain us if you want to count down or up. Also please look at the answers and interact with them

Answer (score 1):

This problem is happening because the Javascript execution and page rendering are actually occurring in the same execution thread. This means that while the code is executing the browser will not be redrawing the page because running JavaScript blocks the updating of the DOM like in your example.

To solve this you can use the `setTimeout()` which allows you to specify a function that will be executed once after a set number of milliseconds. Now, there will be gaps in between the code execution in which the browser will get the chance to redraw the page. now, when you actually pass 0 as the the delay argument. it will schedule the callback to be run asynchronously, after the shortest possible delay - which will be around after JavaScript thread of execution is not busy (the callback function will be waiting in the callback queue to be pulled by the event loop to be handled after a really short time)

```js
function count() {
   var counter = 100;
   var max = 1000;

   function timeoutLoop() {
      document.getElementById('cc').innerHTML = counter;
      if (++counter < max){
         setTimeout(timeoutLoop, 0);
      }
   }

   setTimeout(timeoutLoop, 0);
}

count();
```

```html
<div id="cc">

</div>
```

More about the `event loop` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Great article about browser rendering - https://developpaper.com/the-process-of-browser-rendering-web-pages/

Comment: @mplungjan your code will keep trying to update `cc`'s `.innerHTML` every seconds for the whole time the document will be alive.

Comment: "after the shortest possible delay" this is only true for the first 4 iterations, at the 5th there will be a minimum delay of 4ms (and actually in Chrome there is still a minimum 1ms delay, even for the first iterations, while they are working on removing that one).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you were using a while loop, instead use an if statement to check whether the counter has reached 1000. See below:

```js
var counter = 100;
function countdown() {

 if(counter < 1000) {
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
    document.getElementById('cc').innerHTML = counter;
    

  }
}
    
countdown();
setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="cc"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much brother.

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the browser time to breathe

Also why have a loop when setInterval loops?

And you want to count down. not up I guess
Also we want to stop the counting
Lastly we can save a bracket

```js
let counter = 10; // 10 to show it works
let tId;
const cc = document.getElementById('cc');

function countdown() {
  if (counter === 0) { 
    cc.innerHTML = "DONE!";
    clearInterval(tId); // stop
    return
  }  
  //  console.log(counter);
  cc.innerHTML = counter;
  counter--;
}
countdown();
tId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="cc"></span>
```